# My Cities: Skylines cities are all gone!

Tags: steam, technical-issues, cities-skylines

Every time Steam updates, when I click on the desktop shortcut to open the game, Steam opens a box asking if I would like to install *Cities: Skylines*. I have not found any way around this. This means that whenever Steam updates, **ALL** of my progress is completely lost. I have tried going to `Steam>Settings>Downloads>Steam Library Folders>Program Files\Steam` then selecting Repair Library Folder. I also have gone to `Program Files > Steam > steamapps > common > Cities_Skylines` then running "Cities". All these direct me to the install box. Is there anyway *at all* to be able to play C:S *with* my cities?

**Update:**

Now it has happened to a different game as well, Home Wars! (https://store.steampowered.com/app/645790/Home_Wars/) Please help me, this is getting outrageous!!

Comment: "Every time Steam updates..." just to be clear, are you referring to a Steam client update or a CS game update?

Comment: @sirreldar The Steam client.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure that this worked but it worked for someone with the same issue, but apparently, you have to show hidden files.

Retrieved from https://steamcommunity.com/app/255710/discussions/0/1741103267274566026/

Comment: That is not my issue. This person, to my understanding, did get into the actual game without any trouble, whereas I cannot get any further than the launcher.